# Simple web form that writes to a database... access web form or custom ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ms-access-2010

I am working in a school and we recently installed a new server running WinServer 2008R2. I want to be able to point people to a URL on our intranet and have them fill out a simple registration form and have this data written to a database. It would also be nice to have some data auto-populate (such as their name).

Is it overkill to set up a sharepoint server and try to do this with Access Webforms? 
Could I use something like dotnetnuke and find a module that works? Or how about options for writing custom forms?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a web form to fill in and collect data is not too difficult.

Have a look at http://www.asp.net/get-started. It is something you will find a lot of tutorials for. You might like to consider MySQL or SQL Server Express for your database. A Sharepoint server would definitely be overkill, unless you have some large ideas about sharing documents.

Comment: Why MySQL instead of SQL Server Express?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would definately not go with sharepoint for such a simple task.  Besides money issues sharepoint is difficult to properly set up.  Even with custom ECT's within sharepoint administration is a nightmare.

I would personally create a simple asp.net web form with some standard fields and you could use SQL Server or mySQL to push this data into a database.  As for default values, that depends on how you want to set the fields, you could use windows authentication and set their user name to their NT login.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is way too overkill for something like this. Same for DotNetNuke or any other platform. Just do a simple ASP.NET page with an Access back end. I doubt you'll need anything bigger like SQL Server Express, although that might be a good learning experience.

Comment: Access is almost never a good idea for a website, unless it is a very small private site.

Comment: Which seems to be the case. Looks like an internal school app. SQL Server Express is definitely better, but it is more difficult to install and setup. I would suggest using Access for now, especially if there's a need for a "quick fix". One can always deploy a small SQL Server instance later and change the code to point to that (a trivial task).

Comment: A community college located in the Liberties with a public site is going to get quite a few hits.